# Excel VBS Date Issue (Issue with DATE after convert XLSX to TXT)

Tags: excel, date, datetime, vbscript, vba

This is the simple solution to convert XLSX to TXT file (Tab delimited)

```
Const xlText = -4158

Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
For I = 0 to objArgs.Count - 1

    FullName = objArgs(I)
    FileName = Left(objArgs(I), InstrRev(objArgs(I), ".") )

    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.application")
    set objExcelBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(FullName)

    objExcel.application.visible=false
    objExcel.application.displayalerts=false

    objExcelBook.SaveAs FileName & "txt", xlText

    objExcel.Application.Quit
    objExcel.Quit   

    Set objExcel = Nothing
    set objExcelBook = Nothing

Next
```

The issue is that DATE after it coverted, changed from dd\mm\yyyy to mm\dd\yyyy

Region and other settings on my pc set up to dd\mm\yyyy (United Kingdom)

Any idea about how to make sure that this VBS script will keep the date format the same.

**May be any issue with xlText number????**

Have tried (no success)

```
xlTextMac   19
xlTextMSDOS 21
xlTextPrinter   36
xlTextWindows   20
xlUnicodeText   42
```

Thank you.

**P.S. Any suggestions? Any ideas?**

I Have the same VBS script to convert XLS to CSV and again, dates are converted to US format. (((

**This is only things which i found, but still can't figure it out.**

[Excel 2007 Save worksheet as CSV differs to save worksheet as csv in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669112/excel-2007-save-worksheet-as-csv-differs-to-save-worksheet-as-csv-in-vba)

PART SOLUTION:

> objExcelBook.Columns("A:ZZ").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

Add this line before the SAVEAS. BUT this will add additional columns, which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Open the excel file and click in a date cell. What does it look like in the top left hand corner?

Comment: in original file = e.g. 27/02/2017

Comment: After convert = 02/27/2017

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid maybe any issue with xlText number???

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762834/saving-to-csv-in-excel-loses-regional-date-format has a number of workarounds. Can you just confirm that when you inspect the CSV file, you are inspecting in notepad?

Comment: I open it with Notepad++

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have to use the format which original data are provided. Basically ideally I need that VBS will not change the format of the date at all.

Comment: It's not VBS doing it, it's the Excel exporter. You'll probably need to write some additional code to explicitly format or change the date value while it's in excel, before you export it. For example the link I posted originally says "If you use a Custom format, rather than one of the pre-selected Date formats, the export to CSV will keep your selected format". So I suggest you test this manually. That is go into your excel sheet, set the date column to a "custom format" of dd/mm/yyyy and export it manually and see if it works. If it does, you just need to add this to your VBS

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid If I save manually always everything is fine. I do not need to change anything, any format and so on. The only when it is happening is when I use VBS. I understood the I can put a line that specific column will be formed as date properly.The issue is, that I working with big value of different xls spreadsheets from customers, and to adapt VBS converter to each one, is a bit .. not what I'm looking for... I need something what will work for any xls files and will not convert the date.

Comment: I just reproduced your exact issue. Let me do some experimentation.

Comment: I tried changing the export format to 4 other numbers - no change. I went through all of my regional settings and they are all D/M/Y but still it exports as M/D/Y

Comment: And I do not know how to solve it, it keep changing to US, so it mean SOMEWHERE it using this US date format, and I can't understand from where..

Comment: Excel is full of these things. In my experience it is a very unreliable data interchange format. But we're stuck with it because it's so easy for end users to fill in.

Comment: I just recorded a macro of me saving as CSV. It saved the CSV correctly. I reran the macro. _it saved it in US format_ WTF

Comment: If these excel files are generated manually by users you're not going to know what format the dates are anyway. Perhaps you could expand on the full data flow. What creates this files? What uses the CSV files?

Comment: I need csv or txt(tab delimited) to create .dbf files for further process. The dates should be always dd/mm/yyyy (unless user specify otherwise). Need to find what is used to convert files, this is where should be solution.

Comment: If you always know which column contains dates I suggest you add some VBS code to apply custom format before export. I just tested and a manual custom format preserved the date format. If you don't know which will be the date field then the question is: how will you automatically import this into DBF? I understand that if you crack the file converter you'll solve your problem, but in my experience, excel just does these things and no one can explain why!

Comment: I will try to figure it out, but thank you for effort.

Comment: Good luck with it