# I need to identify and convert variously formatted dates in Excel VBA into a standard output format

Tags: excel, vba, date

I frequently receive data sets from clients in CSV format.  I am trying to create a set of Excel VBA Macros to pre-clean the data.  One issue in particular I have is dealing with dates.

In a set I'm looking at right now, some date fields contain dates formatted this way:

```
2016-03-25 14:18:03
```

While others are formatted like this:

```
2016-03-25 14:18:02.566000
```

When Excel opens the CSV, the  first format, the one without fractions of a second, displays as 3/25/2016 14:18, and when that cell is selected, the formula bar contains 3/25/2016 2:18:03 PM.  For the second format, it displays in mm:ss.0 format (18:02.6), and if I select the field in excel, it shows the same way as the first in the formula bar.

I'm trying to write my macro to identify if the field is a date.  The `IsDate` function only identifies the first format as a date.  When I look to see what value is passed in for the second value, it has apparently converted the date to decimal value (in this case `42454.59586080556`).  When I try to format this as a date, it throws an error.

Currently, in Excel VBA, I am looping through all used cells in the active sheet (`ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells`).  Fore each cell I then use: `If IsDate(Cell.Value) Then` and if it's identified as a date, it gets formatted in my specified output format.  However, when it passes in the decimal, it's not a date, so it skips the formatting.

I have other fields that are integers and decimals in the data, so I can't simply add another if statement to handle the value if it comes through this way.

The only thing I can think of right now is to try converting the decimal to date (I've seen a method for that, but can't seem to find it at the moment), THEN test to see if it's in an expected range, and if it's not, then keep the decimal, and if it is, keep the date.  But this doesn't seem viable.

I could write it to specify columns, but the data doesn't always come in with the columns in the same order (different sources, different formats).

The core problem appears to be that Excel is trying to translate the data in the field when it opens the file. There doesn't seem to be a way to prevent Excel from doing this that I can find.

So... does anyone have any good ideas?  Right now, I'm having to open the files and manually re-format the dates on each file... and when some of the files have millions of lines of data, this is extremely time consuming for a hands-on process.

Comment: Do the columns have consistent headers? It would be difficult to accurately accomplish this totally blind as you can technically convert all integers and decimals to dates.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The data comes from various sources.   I have 3 or 4 sources that are MOSTLY consistent, but not entirely.  I've been slowly working on a C# app to handle most of the conversion, but that's been a long row to hoe. The CSV formats used aren't consistent (sometimes quoted fields, sometimes not) and with commas, quotes, tabs, and line breaks in note fields that sometimes kick new lines or columns, and sometimes don't, it's maddening. (And no, I can't demand a consistent format, we have to take what's given).

Comment: In my experience Excels handling of csv files, especially when they contain dates, is ... challenging.  I usually end up writing my own csv handler.  [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669112/excel-2007-save-worksheet-as-csv-differs-to-save-worksheet-as-csv-in-vba/8674433?r=SearchResults&s=2|42.4931#8674433) that writes a csv.  Similar principles to read

Comment: Thanks.  I'll take a look at that.

The problem I've been running into is knowing where a valid column and line break are.  There are often note fields that are absolute chaos.  The people doing the exporting don't bother escaping quotes or any other characters so sometimes I might have a column that starts with a comma and the text is quoted, sometimes not, and sometimes there's quotes, commas, tabs, etc inside the notes, and when I try to handle the csv, I frequently end up with a mess.  Somehow, Excel figures out the column breaks better than anything else I've found so far.

Comment: The decimal is of a day. So .5 should be 12pm.

Answer (score 1):

Gathering from your comments, you would most likely have to take the hacky approach of comparing the converted values of your integers/decimals and seeing if they fall within a date range like:

```
If IsDate(Cell.Value) Then
    'Do Stuff
ElseIf IsNumeric(Cell.Value) And InStr(1, Cell.Value, ".") > 0 Then
    If CDate(Left(Cell.Value, InStr(1, Cell.Value, ".") - 1)) > lowDate And CDate(Left(Cell.Value, InStr(1, Cell.Value, ".") - 1)) < highDate Then
        'Do Stuff
    End If
End If
```

Where `lowDate` and `highDate` are variables you'd initialize and use as boundaries.

Comment: That's kind-of what I'm afraid of.  I'm just trying to avoid that because there's almost certainly going to be values that are integer/decimal that get converted.  C'est la vie.

Comment: Another hacky approach I'd suggest would be to use the `Len()` of the "passed in" values to identify which ones are the strangely pre-formatted dates. Unless all of your decimal values are just as long or all the date values _aren't_, in which case, that wouldn't work either.

Comment: Actually, I tried that.  Some of the note fields occasionally start with a date, so I tried checking to see if the field was less than 30 characters (which rules out the notes) and the first 19 were a date... I see what you say about the decimal date formats... I might be able to work with that (if is numeric and there's N characters before the decimal point... I'll have to tinker with that).

Comment: Messy data is always awkward to wrangle in, but it sure does inspire some clever solutions. Let me know what you come up with, hopefully one of the ideas here works out for you!