# VBA CSV Export Remove Trailing Commas

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I've been trying to troubleshoot a macro to export an excel worksheet to CSV but it is creating trailing commas at the end of rows and for blank rows which creates an error in the program that needs to read it.

Weirdly, if I open the CSV in excel after and adjust the alignment of the text, that removes the trailing commas. But, I need it to be automated and don't ever intend on actually opening the CSV file, just saving and immediately uploading, so going in and fixing the file after is not an option.

Would anyone have any suggestions of additions to my code to remove the trailing commas?

Code for reference:

```
    Sub ExportAsCSV()

        Sheets("Example").Select
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$CQ$10000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"

        Dim MyFileName As String
        Dim CurrentWB As Workbook, TempWB As Workbook
 
        Set CurrentWB = ActiveWorkbook
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy

        Set TempWB = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1).Range("$A$1:$CQ$10000")
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End With

    MyFileName = CurrentWB.Path & "\" & Left(CurrentWB.Name, InStrRev(CurrentWB.Name, ".") - 1) & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd") & ".csv"


    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    TempWB.SaveAs Filename:=MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
    TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    Sheets("Example").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$CP$10000").AutoFilter Field:=1

    
    End Sub
```

Example of what I mean:[trailing commas visible in notepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CL2b7.png)

Comment: Try adding `.Value = .Value` after the `.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats`.

Comment: Excel csv handling can be fickle. 
I'd reccomendwriting yourowncsv handler.  [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8674433)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this sub do most of you need and you are able to modify to do the rest.

```
Sub CVSDemostration()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Example")
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = sh.Range("$A$1:$CQ$100")
    
    Dim valuesInRange As Variant
    valuesInRange = rng.Value
    Dim MyFile As String
    
    Dim iRows As Long, iColumns As Long
    iRows = UBound(valuesInRange, 1)
    iColumns = UBound(valuesInRange, 2)
    
    Dim iRow As Long, iColumn As Long
    
    Dim isRowEmptly As Boolean
    isRowEmptly = True
    
    MyFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1) & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd") & ".csv"
    Open MyFile For Output As #1
    
    For iRow = 1 To iRows
        For iColumn = 1 To iColumns
            If Not IsEmpty(valuesInRange(iRow, iColumn)) Then
                Write #1, valuesInRange(iRow, iColumn),
                isRowEmptly = False
            End If
        Next iColumn
        If Not isRowEmptly Then Write #1,
        isRowEmptly = True
    Next iRow
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend adding the SkipBlanks argument to the code.  Set it to true so that blank cells are not pasted.

[This page](https://www.excelhowto.com/macros/excel-vba-copy-and-paste-a-range/#:%7E:text=One%20of%20the%20most%20common,data%20in%20the%20target%20cell.) can show you how to do that.